# React - new Date month is +1?

Tags: javascript, date

I've looked at this a few different times but cant figure out why its doing this:
I have created a new date but when react compiles it, it is printing out the date incorrectly from what ive written

```javascript
function ExpenseItem() {
    const expenseDate = new Date(2023,3,8);
    const expenseTitle = 'Test';
    const expenseAmount = 200.00;

    return (
        <div className={"expense-item"}>
            <div>{expenseDate.toDateString()}</div>
            <div className={"expense-item__description"}>
                <h2>{expenseTitle}</h2>
                <div className={"expense-item__price"}>£{expenseAmount}</div>
            </div>
        </div>)
```

When it compiles, it prints out the date as:
Sat Apr 08 2023

If I change the month value in the Date to 0, then it prints out January. Is this something that is supposed to happen?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). Months are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as per the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#examples) the month is zero indexed while the day is not.